# How to pass user and password in new_handle in curl R

Tags: r, curl

I have curl request that is working file, which is as follows:

`curl -XGET "https://xxxx.com/xxx" -u "username:password"`

How I want to do it using `curl` package in R

I have following code,

`library(curl)
 clCall <- new_handle(url = 'https://xxxx.com/xxx')
 handle_setopt(clCall, customrequest = "XGET")`

Now I don't know how to pass username and password in this curl request

Comment: have you tried this 

clCall <- new_handle(url = 'https://xxxx.com/xxx', userpwd='user:password')

Comment: didn't work, I tried userpwd, and user

Comment: what error did it throw? Have you tried using package `RCurl` instead of `curl`?

Comment: it is throwing 405 error, I am using curl. package

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should set `httpauth` and `userpwd` options too:

```r
h <- curl::new_handle()
curl::handle_setopt(
    handle = h,
    httpauth = 1,
    userpwd = "user:passwd"
)
resp <- curl::curl_fetch_memory("https://httpbin.org/basic-auth/user/passwd", handle = h)
jsonlite::fromJSON(rawToChar(resp$content))
#> $authenticated
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $user
#> [1] "user"
```