# Is there a way to download several Excel files from password protected url using R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to download multiple excel files from a password protected website that I have log in credentials for. Is there a package or method to get R to plug in my credentials so I can mass download the excel files?

I tried to XML to no avail. Any packages anyone reccomends?

Comment: Take a look at [This previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46754764/4752675)

Comment: [`httr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html) and [`rvest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/index.html) fully support authenticated connections, I suggest you read the documentation for those two packages.

Comment: You can use the R package RSelenium to do this It would be usefule if you could provide the website. We could provide a more precise answer.